# How can i print alphabetical letters diagonaly using MASM?

Tags: assembly, masm

im trying this code but i was not able perfectly print diagonally in alphabet order.. can you help me to this code?
[program output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9EoP.jpg)

```
.model small
.stack
.code

start:


mov cx,26
mov bh,00
mov ah,02h
mov dl,41h
mov dh,02h
again:
int 10h
int 21h
inc dl
inc dh
loop again

mov ah,4ch
int 21h
end start
```

Comment: click the program output screenshot to see the output of the code.

Comment: `int 10h / ah=02h` uses `dl` as the cursor horizontal position.

Comment: what changes i should made?

Comment: Use two separate variables for the column and the character, and move the appropriate one into `dl` before each interrupt.

Comment: sorry but i am still new in assembly language. can you show the sample code?

Comment: hi michael please show me the code.. thanks

Comment: You have free `bl`, so you can keep the character there, and do `xchg bl,dl` between interrupts. Plus you will have to add additional `inc bl` ahead of loop. Try it and edit/post what you got.

Comment: BTW, the default text mode is 80x25 characters, so your coordinates will go out of screen toward end. Either switch to text mode with more lines, or don't even bother outputting the last chars ... although they probably just overwrite second "page" in video-RAM, so no real damage in this case, but it's good to be very precise with assembly and practice that. As usually in asm any unintentional memory overwrite ends with "very difficult to track" bug effects.

Comment: i stil dont get.. would you please show me how to code?

Comment: No, try SOMETHING, so I can see what you don't get and try to help you. It's sort of trivial, if you understand x86 ASM, so you have some real problem under your code problem, and I would rather address that one, than giving you 5 lines of code you will never understand. Maybe also explain if that code is something you wrote, so you already understand a bit of asm, or it's something you got and you are just trying to understand how it works. ... Do you actually know what `mov dl,41h` does? I mean both in CPU low level terms, and it's purpose from programmers point of view?

Comment: as i told you.. im new to this.. im not yet fully understand how this works.. if i know i would not bother to post a question here and solve it myself.

Comment: "not yet fully understand how this works" I can of course *fully* teach you x86 assembly programming, but my hour rate is probably kinda out of your reach (although? Around $30/hour is maybe possible, I like this stuff, so I wouldn't ask my normal hour rate). In case you want *partial* help -> you show your part (what you already understand), then maybe I will answer here at SO for free. If *"not yet fully"* is "pretty much nothing", then go to some tutorials and asm lessons, there's lot of stuff on internet for free (with various quality unfortunately).

Comment: JFYI I have personal difficulties to deal with persons ignoring my questions, yet expecting some kind of answer from me... Feels like "this goes nowhere, let do something meaningful somewhere else".

Comment: i already did that... and theres no tutorial out there how to print it diagonally using simple looping.. i know how to print it horizontal and vertical in alphabetical order.. but to print it in diagonal, i cant.. that is why i post a question here.. sorry i cant pay you and i dont have to..

Comment: Thank you by the way for your time.. :)

Comment: Yes, and if you would understand how those vertical/horizontal works, it would be easy to fix your current code, which is *so* close to what you want. That's actually what making me afraid to just give you the code, it looks like you don't understand at all, what those instructions do. If you want more help from me, either try to apply *"Use two separate variables for the column and the character"* advice and show your new code (with comments what you don't get), or answer (thoroughly!) my question from comments (the one about `mov dl,41h` from time 12:16:11Z).

Comment: IMO you don't need tutorial how to print it diagonally. You need tutorial how CPU works, what are registers, how it works with computer memory, and finally search for documentation of BIOS `int 10h` service and DOS `int 21h` service, so you know what you are using in that code. That will take lot more time to get through and understand, but then you will be able to do in ASM much more than print letters diagonally (and through BIOS and DOS interrupt ... you have no idea how slow this code would be back on original PC XT :), like maybe even tenth of second, for only 26 chars!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the problems with this code stem from the fact that both the BIOS function 02h (SetCursor) and the DOS function 02h (WriteCharacter) use the `DL` register as a parameter. Unluckily for you the meaning is different in this cases. Several solutions exist. Using the free register `BL` to keep a separate character code was suggested by Ped7g.

A simple solution that I present is not using the DOS output function at all, and writing to the display with BIOS function 0Eh (TeletypeCharacter). This function does not rely on `DL` as a parameter. It rather uses the `AL` register.

```
.model small
.stack
.code

start:

mov al, "A"    <<<First character
mov bh, 0      <<<Display page 0
mov cx, 25     <<<Iteration count
mov dl, 0      <<<Start at column 0
mov dh, 0      <<<Start at row 0
again:
mov ah, 02h    <<<BIOS function SetCursor
int 10h
mov ah, 0Eh    <<<BIOS function TeleType
int 10h
inc dl         <<<Next column
inc dh         <<<Next row
inc al         <<<Next character
loop again

mov ah, 4Ch
int 21h
end start
```

When working on the standard textscreen there are 80 columns and 25 rows. You should not position the cursor off-screen!  The most iterations your program should perform therefore is 25.